# Android: Bluetooth failed to get port number

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm running into a problem using Bluetooth in my app. It seems that after 28 `BluetoothSocket`/`BluetoothServerSockets` have been created, all of the ports are taken. The sockets don't need to be opened simultaneously, it's just 28 sockets since Bluetooth was enabled.

This can be reproduced using the BluetoothChat sample provided in the [Android Samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html). Simply open and close the app 15 times (the app creates 2 sockets each time). On the 15th time, it will crash and will continue to crash until you disable and then re-enable Bluetooth:

```
12-06 18:43:58.177: E/BluetoothSocket(18530): bindListen, fail to get port number, exception: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed, read ret: -1
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530): Socket Type: Insecurelisten() failed
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530): java.io.IOException: Error: -1
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.createNewRfcommSocketAndRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:1035)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:982)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService$AcceptThread.<init>(BluetoothChatService.java:280)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService.start(BluetoothChatService.java:119)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.onResume(BluetoothChat.java:131)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-06 18:43:58.193: E/BluetoothChatService(18530):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any way to free the ports after the socket is closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can verify this behavior on device that I have here; although the number of times required to crash in the same way varies by device (I think 20-25 times were required on the Galaxy Nexus running 4.2) so the available number of port handles seems to vary.  I can also contribute the information that the issue is not a memory leak in the sample app (or your app for that matter) as all instances of `BluetoothSocket` have been released and closed by Dalvik.  The steps listed here only tests the issue on `BluetoothServerSocket`, so its unclear if the problem is specifically related to that, though it seems unlikely.

At least on my devices, you cannot even start the app up again until toggling the Bluetooth adapter's status, so the problem is definitely in the underlying management of the connections on the stack.

I would file a bug with steps to reproduce here http://b.android.com and I'd be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I've filed a bug here: [#41110](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41110). It took 15 times to crash the app on both my Galaxy Nexus and my Nexus 7 running 4.2.1. My Nexus One never crashed, so hopefully it's only a JB issue.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had to delve into coming up with a solution for this. Upgrading Android was not an option.

It turns out that if, instead of destroying and recreating mAcceptThread each time a connection is established / broken, keep the original instance and re-use it. This minimizes the bug's effect on your app.

From the BluetoothChatService file, in the connected() function, do not cancel mAcceptThread:

```
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
...
...
...
// Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device 
//(Rather stay listening so comment out the cancel line!!) 
//If necessary, use some other state to prevent a second connection.
//DONT CANCEL: if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
...
...
```

In the AcceptThread class, modify the loop in the run() function:

```
            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
//OLD LOOP:            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
//(Rather use STATE_NONE so the loop will only stop when the service does)
            while (mState != STATE_NONE)
```

There may be other things to do in your code to properly implement the idea.

Answer (score 0):

To re-connect i use in a timed handler in the fragment:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MainActivity.mac);
                    // Attempt to connect to the device
                    mChatService.connect(device, true);
```

To solve the issue "fails when re-connecting for more than 28 times" i commented every time the service re-starts itself when loosing connection:

```
//BluetoothChatService.this.start();
```

also i commented out all the parts where the socket closes:

```
//socket.close();

//mmServerSocket.close();

//mmSocket.close();

//mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
```

and added a not null detection for the accept thread and connected thead not to fail:

```
if(mAdapter != null) {
                        tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                                MY_UUID_SECURE);
                    }else{
                        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                        //mState = STATE_NONE;
                    }
```

and

```
if(mmServerSocket != null) {
                        socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                    }
```

Still i get random connection drops, but the service re connects and everything works.